# Python Tkinter GUI Form to search in a database, but some fields can be blank

Tags: python, database, forms, user-interface, tkinter

I'm building a tool to search database records using a form builded in Tkinter. The problem is that I don't know which fields are gonna get filled, a user could just want to search by ID and not fill the other form fields. I don't think writting a query for each case in an IF statement should be a solution, I bet there's more simple ways.

Here's my form (the names are in spanish, I do apologize for that):

```
global buscar
global buscar_ni_entry

buscar = Toplevel(ventana_intervencion)
buscar.title("Buscar Registros")
buscar.geometry("400x500")

buscar_frame = LabelFrame(buscar, text="Criterios de busqueda")
buscar_frame.pack(padx=10, pady=10)

buscar_ni_label = Label(buscar_frame, text="N INTERVENCION:")
buscar_ni_label.grid(row=0, column=0, pady=20, padx=20)
buscar_ni_entry = Entry(buscar_frame)
buscar_ni_entry.grid(row=0, column=1, pady=20, padx=20)

buscar_responsable_label = Label(buscar_frame, text="RESPONSABLE:")
buscar_responsable_label.grid(row=1, column=0, pady=20, padx=20)
buscar_responsable_entry = Entry(buscar_frame)
buscar_responsable_entry.grid(row=1, column=1, pady=20, padx=20)

buscar_centro_label = Label(buscar_frame, text="CENTRO:")
buscar_centro_label.grid(row=2, column=0, pady=20, padx=20)
buscar_centro_entry = Entry(buscar_frame)
buscar_centro_entry.grid(row=2, column=1, pady=20, padx=20)

buscar_ti_label = Label(buscar_frame, text="TIPO INTERVENCION:")
buscar_ti_label.grid(row=3, column=0, pady=20, padx=20)
buscar_ti_entry = Entry(buscar_frame)
buscar_ti_entry.grid(row=3, column=1, pady=20, padx=20)

buscar_referencia_label = Label(buscar_frame, text="REFERENCIA:")
buscar_referencia_label.grid(row=4, column=0, pady=20, padx=20)
buscar_referencia_entry = Entry(buscar_frame)
buscar_referencia_entry.grid(row=4, column=1, pady=20, padx=20)

buscar_boton = Button(buscar, text="Buscar Registros", command=buscar_base_datos)
buscar_boton.pack(padx=20, pady=20)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to build the SQL statement dynamically based on the input values.

Something like:

```py
conditions = []
args = []

value = buscar_ni_entry.get().strip()
if value:
    conditions.append('some_field = ?')  # ? for sqlite, %s for mysql
    args.append(value)

# do the same for other entries

# then build the SQL
where = ' AND '.join(conditions)
sql = f'SELECT * FROM some_table WHERE {where}'
cursor.execute(sql, args)
```